# How to flash the title bar rapidly in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to replicate the behaviour that you get when you try to click outside a modal dialog such as created by AfxMessageBox(). The title bar flashes rapdily several times, and a beep sounds. Using CWnd::FlashWindow() I can only get one or two very slow flashes. What is the missing link?

Comment: I don't know if its in MFC, but `FlashWindowEx` lets you control the speed and number of flashes.

Comment: @chris: Win32 functions don't have to be "in" MFC in order for an MFC function to call them. Calling `FlashWindowEx` is probably the right answer here.

Comment: @GregHewgill, Yes, I meant I don't know if MFC wrapped that part in or anything, or if the native call had to be made manually.

Comment: You're probably right... although the Microsoft documentation is full of broken links and missing references on the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6dxfy6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), I found `CWnd::FlashWindowEx`, which lets you specify the timeout between each flash. If you want five flashes to take a total of one second, specify 200 as the timeout value (milliseconds) and 5 as the number of flashes.

```
windowObject.FlashWindowEx(FLASHW_CAPTION, 5, 200);
```

For the beep, you can do something like the native [`MessageBeep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
MessageBeep(MB_OK);
```

Comment: Looking at precisely the same docs, there is no reference to this function from the CWnd::FlashWindow() page, and the link to the SDK FlashWindowEx page on this one is a broken link. Thanks, Microsoft. Also, it lists it as available in MSVC2005... but so far my MSVC2005 can't find the function. Hmmmm....

Comment: @omatai, Yes, the documentation can be very annoying to trawl through at certain times. I can't offer any experience on using these with MFC either, sorry.

Comment: @omatai, A VS 2012 MFC app seems to have no trouble finding it as part of `CWnd`.